# Artefacts on table borders in Adobe PDF Reader

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-reader

I'm getting artefacts on my table borders when converting from word documents to pdf. You can see these at the circled points in the image below: there are small vertical 'stubs' where there should be no vertical line at all.

[image: Illustration of artefacts]

I get this or similar problems when using Word's built-in export function, pdf printers, and Adobe's Word plugin. Increasing the line thickness to 1pt does not help.

The problem appears in Adobe Reader, but not the built-in viewers inside Firefox and Edge.

The artefacts disappear in Adobe Reader if I zoom in enough, or if I disable the 'enhance thin lines' option - but I can't really tell other people to adjust their settings to view the document, and turning the setting off reduces the quality overall.

Can anyone suggest anything to help resolve this problem?

---

**Response to comment**

Result of removing internal borders:

[image: Internal borders removed]

Comment: Go into the Word Document, to the table, right click, Table Properties and go to the Borders section and remove the interior lines. Then reconvert to PDF.  That works for me.

Comment: @John thanks, I've updated the question after trying what you suggest - the problem remains (and I'd also like to keep the internal borders)

Comment: If you keep the internal borders, then Adobe will use them

Comment: @John I think I might have misunderstood you. I went to Bonders and Shading, and removed all of the internal borders - is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: Yes.  Now try reconverting the document to PDF

Comment: @John OK, I've done that - you can see the result in the second image in the question. The internal borders are removed, but some of the vertical subs are still there.

Comment: You may need to remove the horizontal borders and vertical as well and just ad horizontal and see if that works. That should remove the little tick mark.

Comment: @John still no luck when using Word's export feature, but removing the internal borders does help when using Microsoft's PDF printer. This is useful to know, but in this case I would like to keep the internal borders so it doesn't solve my problem exactly.

Comment: What happens if you change the thickness of the strokes slightly?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad depends on the viewer zoom level. Increasing to 1pt still shows the problem when viewed at 100% (but not if I zoom into 150%), and increasing again to 1.5pt does show the problem at 75% but not at 100%.